# Casting multiple value.var controled by fun.aggregate

Tags: r, dataframe, dcast

I have the following dataset

```
client_id <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B")
value <- c(10, 35, 20, 30, 50, 40, 30, 40, 30, 40, 10)
period_30 <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
period_60 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
sign <- c("D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D")

data <- data.frame(client_id, value, period_30, period_60, sign)
```

I can use this code to count the number of different splits per given period with the code below:

```
library(data.table)
test<- dcast(setDT(data), client_id ~ paste0("period_30", sign), value.var = "period_30", sum)
```

But I would like to also calculate the value as per the different splits.

The **expected outcome** would look like this:

```
client_id       av.value_period_30_sign_D   av.value_period_60_sign_D   av.value_period_30_sign_C   av.value_period_30_sign_D
    A                     34.16667                      NaN                  NaN                                   NaN
    B                     30.00000                    34.16667               NaN                               27.50000
```

And then, it should be extendable to additional splits, like average value of sign X, of type X in period 1.

I am not sure if the desired output is doable with this approach. But I was looking at the `fun.aggregate` argument. Perhaps it could be used in combination with *multiple `value.var` arguments*?

Update: Joel's code answers the first part of the question.

```
client_id   sign    period_30   period_60 
    A         D     34.16667    34.16667
    B         D     30.00000    34.16667
    B         C     NaN         27.50000
```

But how do I transpose the variables and assign the names as per the splits automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another method(would be faster) is using `data.table`

Based on the edit made to the question :(hope the code is self explanatory now)

```
library(data.table)
data1 <- setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(value[x==1])),
                      .SDcols = period_30:period_60,
                      by = .(client_id, sign)]
# `dcast` if also from `data.table` package
dcast(data1, client_id~sign, drop = FALSE, value.var = c("period_30", "period_60"))
#   client_id period_30_C period_30_D period_60_C period_60_D
#1:         A          NA    34.16667          NA    34.16667
#2:         B         NaN    30.00000        27.5    34.16667
```

Comment: Hello Joel, I just updates the question. Indeed, your code answers the first part of the problem. Do you have any idea how I can solve the transposing/naming part? It would be extremely helpful for me.

Comment: Thank you Joel! Its a life saver :)

Comment: Hi Joel, I have been testing the code with different datasets, and I realized that the grouping fails. So if there is more than one user or sign, the result is incorrect. Do you have any idea what might be going wrong? It works fine for one user tho.

Comment: Perhaps something similar to this could be a solution: 

check <- setDT(data)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {ifelse(x == 1, NA, sum(data$value))}),
                          .SDcols = PERIOD_30:PERIOD_365,
                          by = (client_id)]

Answer (score 0):

One could use `dplyr`; Given the current df (=test):

```
df %>% group_by(sign) %>% summarize(avg.val=mean(value),avg.period1=mean(period_1),avg.period2=mean(period_2),avg.period3=mean(period_3))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
    sign avg.val avg.period1 avg.period2 avg.period3
   <chr>   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Credit   39.50        0.50         1.0           1
2  Debit   36.25        0.25         0.5           1
```

You could change the grouping variable  in `group` to meet your needs.

Comment: I need to group by multiple splits - customer, sign, type. And second, with this approach you have to manually label each variable. So if I have 10 periods, 10 signs, 10 types, it becomes impossibe to implement :/ Thats why I cant to rely on dcast.

Comment: If I understood correctly, for the second part you could use summarise_each. Also you could group by multiple variables as well. I was just working on the df you provided.