# mixing SDcols with ifelse and grouped variables

Tags: r, function, group-by, data.table

This question is continuation of a previous question I posted, but which I realized fails when I conduct grouping. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256272/casting-multiple-value-var-controled-by-fun-aggregate)

I need to calculate the mean of the **value** variable, grouped per **client** and **sign**, if the transaction occured in a specific period.

My attempt:

```
library(data.table)
client_id <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B")
value <- c(10, 35, 20, 30, 50, 40, 30, 40, 30, 40, 10)
period_30 <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
period_60 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
sign <- c("D", "D", "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D")

test <- data.frame(client_id, value, period_30, period_60, sign)

result <- setDT(test)[, lapply(.SD, function(i) {ifelse(1 %in% i, mean(test$value), 0)}),
                     .SDcols = period_30:period_60,
                     by=.(client_id, sign)]
```

With the code above the result I get is nonsense, but I believe i am on the right track. I am just not sure how to fix the ifelse statement.

**The expected result is**

```
Client ID     average_value_period30    average_value_period60
    A                    22.5                       29
```

Anyone?

Comment: Based on the data you showed, the `average_value_period60` is 22.5 (if I am not wrong) for client_ID A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need

```
setDT(test)[, lapply(.SD, function(i)
     mean(value[i==1])) ,client_id, .SDcols = period_30:period_60]
```

Comment: Well, it gives mean for client A for period 30 of 34.1667. While, this client has two transactions in period 30 with value of 10 and 35. So it should be 45/2 = 22.5. If I take sum for instance, it gives 205 for client A in period 30, while it should be 45. I dont get it. :S

Comment: @Prometheus For the period 30, I also get 22.5

Comment: @Prometheus  Are you using the newer version of data.table?  I am using 1.10.0

Comment: update: no, you are using a newer version. i'll try with 1.10 now.

Comment: I double checked now, the problem was the package version. Thanks! I know it sounds trivial but I lost hours on this problem.